# Использование коллекций в spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, коллекции

Изучаю спринг в основном по видео из ютуб. Мне не понятно, почему часто в примерах используются непотокобезопасные коллекции?

Ведь если я правильно понимаю у спринг бута под капотом томкэт, а у него многопоточка под каждый запрос.

Не будет ли это проблемой и какие коллекции следует использовать?

Comment: Вообще под капотом спринга крутятся, аннотации, прокси объекты и рефлексия, томкат подгружается тогда, когда ты закидываешь депенденси web, коллекции: ConcurrentHashMap/Set/ArrayList

Comment: Чтоб ответить по существу, приведите хотя бы один пример, о котором вы спрашиваете. В таком виде вопрос очень общий, и ответ дать нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не все коллекции должны быть thread-safety, так как не всё в спринг буте идёт через многопоточность.

В отдельных потоках обрабатываются запросы в контроллерах, вот там нужны потокобезопасные коллекции. Как правило это ConcurrentHashMap для мапы, и набор из CopyOnWrite коллекций для листа и сета.
Подробнее об этом [Обзор java.util.concurrent](https://habr.com/ru/company/luxoft/blog/157273/)